# Displaying SQL-data in a table

Tags: php, html

A few months ago, I made a system where people could upload a picture and then those pictures would be displayed in a table with 4 columns. 
Now I am working on a project (to practice my php, I am still learning it) and I would like to use a similar system as below but it should display data from a database.
The result I was trying to achieve is the data being displayed in 2 columns.

```
if ($handle = opendir('images/')) {
    $bool = true;
    while ($bool) {
       $td = 1;
       echo '<tr>';
       while ($td < 4) {
          $file = readdir($handle);
          if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != '.DS_Store') {
             echo '<td>';
             if ($file) {
                echo '<img src="images/'.$file.
                '">';
             } else {
                $bool = false;
             }
             echo '</td>';
             $td++;
          }
       }
       echo '</tr>';
    }
 }
 closedir($handle);
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop there, `while($bool){ ... }`. And what's the point of using `$i`? Do you want to display everything in table cells? If so, then use `<td>...</td>` instead of `<h2>`, `<p>` etc.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. As I mentioned in my post, the code isn't finished since I got stuck. I used the $i to limit the number of columns to 2 since that is the desired result.
Edit: I added the code that I based my code on in the post above

Comment: Both of your code snippets are completely unrelated to each other. Please include only relevant code(*where you need help*) and explain what exactly you're trying to do and what's your expected output, because only that way you can get concrete answers.

Comment: I see. A while ago I made something where you could upload a picture and it would be displayed using the second snippet, I was trying to change that code so that I could display data from a database. I'll try to change the post to make it better but know that English is not my native language so expressing myself can be hard at times. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM webshop";
                if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
                    $bool = true;
                    echo '<table>';
                    while($bool) {
                        $td = 0;
                        echo '<tr>';
                        while($td < 2) {
                            if($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
                                echo '<td>';
                                $title = $fetch['title'];
                                $info = $fetch['info'];
                                /* Commented out for now, will be implemented later
                                $image = $fetch['image'];
                                $price = $fetch['price'];
                                */
                                echo $title;
                            } else {
                                $bool = false;
                            }
                            echo '</td>';
                            $td++;
                        }
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
                }
```

Comment: If your database supports it, you should really get into using stored procedures next. Or parameterized queries...

Comment: Oh, I'll look into it! I am just beginning to learn with storing images in a database and got this method of youtube. Thanks for the useful tip, will be using the tip from now on!